# Viewing Security Camera files in unique format

Tags: video, security, sd-card

So I just got this new security camera and I can download the files to the computer or to an USB drive if I wanted. That is not the problem. The problem is that it shows up as .data files. It does not show the recorded video. How can I see the recorded video or change the file type so I can see it?

Comment: Use the software provided by the manufacturer of the security camera.

Comment: What's the camera make & model, for a start?

Comment: Please provide examples of the full file names used in these files, as well as the make and model of the security camera, so we can assist you wih telling Windows how to open those files. Without that information, we can't help. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]